# CardView-RelativeLayout fill screen 1/4 with RecylerView

Tags: android, xml

I want to divide my screen 1/4. I'm using RecylerView but i couldn't figure out how can i do it (responsively). I did not know which layout should i use.
My xml file:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageIv"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleIv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageIv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageIv"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionIv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/titleIv"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageIv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageIv"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

But the result was 4 items that doesn't fill the screen. I just want them all fill the screen and divide it 1/4.

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No Recyclerview here. Can you explain the details?

Comment: It is my recyclerview's row xml file. And I updated the question with the activity where I call it.

Comment: Recyclerview item içerisindeki elemanların layout'unu 4'e bölmesini mi istiyorsun Halil?

Comment: Daha doğrusu , ekranı 4'e bölmek istiyorum eşit her ekranda responsive olması adına şu şekil bir şey hocam : https://imgur.com/WmtRQyT , https://hizliresim.com/JUaX4G

Comment: Aşağıya cevap ekledim Halit. Recyclerview içerisinde 4 adet eleman olmasını ve bu 4 adet elemanın ekranı 4 e bölmesini istiyorsan, bu durum çok zor olur cünkü recyclerviewde otomatik olarak ScrollView var ve aşağı yukarı ekranın kayacaktır.Bu yuzden şu şekilde yap; yolladığım cevaptaki LinearLayout içerisindeki Recyclerviewlerin yerine 4 adet LinearLayout ya da istediğin herhangi bir eleman kullanabilirsin. Fakat xml de layout_weight="1" ekleme yapmayı unutma.İç kısımlardaki LinearLayout yerine Relative Layout kullanırsan içindeki elemanları istediğin gibi yerleştirebilirsin.

Comment: Deneyip hemen feedback vereceğim hocam, çok teşekkürler.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from what you wrote, you want to put Recyclerview on the screen and divide the screen into 4. Add 4 Recyclerviews on the screen using `LinerarLayout` and assign `layout_weight` values to 1 for each.

In that;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF34FF" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFC107" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00BCD4" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#3F51B5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to explain that this is not the case and you want to have 4 items in `Recyclerview` and divide the screen into 4 equal parts of the screen, it is not very healthy to do such a thing. Because `Recyclerview` naturally contains a `ScrollView`. It will slide up and down the screen automatically. If your screen will only consist of 4 elements, then you may not use `Recyclerview` and use `LinearLayout` directly and add `layout_weight` `value` and assign 1 to each.

In that;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF34FF">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFC107" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00BCD4" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#3F51B5" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of `RelativeLayout`, you can use your desired Layout.